# How can higher resolutions be set on OS X when no monitor is on or attached?

Tags: mac, display, mac-mini, display-settings

Most of the time, I just want to work on the Mac Mini via remote desktop. Is there a way to have it always use a higher resolution on bootup, even when it doesn't detect a display (it's on a KVM switch)?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to get a VGA dummy plug to trick it into thinking there's a monitor connected.  (I know this works fine in most other operating systems so I assume it'll work in OS X.)